# Programming FPGA which is located locally through vivado which is installed on server

Tags: verilog, fpga

We have vivado installed on a server. But I would like to use vivado(on server) to program a bit file on a FPGA which is located locally at my PC. I do not know how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways to do this.

1. You could install Vivado Lab Edition locally, which is a trimmed-down version of Vivado for lab use which does not require a license. You could then simply program the bit file directly.
2. You could install the Vivado Hardware Server locally on your PC, and then connect to it from the instance of Vivado on the server. This might involve some port forwarding and/or modification of firewall rules.

I think #1 is probably easier in most cases.

Both tools are available under the heading "Vivado Lab Solutions" from the [Vivado download page](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/vivado-design-tools.html).